# Advise for Regular Expression pattern needed

Tags: c#, regex

**Sample**

```
EL:123  
가나123.456다라  
123-ABC-456  
123.456+678.890  
AA03-BB1  
$.AB12,00
```

I want to extract any Number Format from String.

Number could be | 100,000 | 20,000.00 | 12.52 | 10,800.082 |

My pattern is

```
@"\d[\d|,|.]+"
```

But.. it does not work for just one digit | 3 | 1 |.

I also tried

```
@"[\d|,|.]+"
```

it should not catch | , | . | only.

What should I do to my regex pattern?

Comment: Replace `+` with `*` and remove `|`. You may try `\d[\d,.]*`. Or `\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*`

Comment: It's something that always messes with me :D instead of **[\d|,|.]** use **(\d|,|.)**

Comment: Use \d+  Plus sign means "at least one or more"

Comment: You guys are so nice! I fix it and it worked. and is there any better resource to learn regular expression than MSDN page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `\d[\d|,|.]+` regex will not find `3` or `1` because `\d` requires 1 digit, and the `+` with `[\d|,|.]+` also requires at least one char more. Note this also matches `1|` since the pipe symbol is considered a literal char in the character class. To match 0 or more occurrences, use `*` quantifier.

To match all those numbers, you may use either

```
 \d[\d,.]*
```

Or, better:

```
\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3A%5B%2C.%5D%5Cd%2B%29*&i=EL%3A123%0D%0A%EA%B0%80%EB%82%98123.456%EB%8B%A4%EB%9D%BC%0D%0A123-ABC-456%0D%0A123.456%2B678.890%0D%0AAA03-BB1%0D%0A%24.AB12%2C00)

**Details**:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[,.]\d+)*` - zero or more (due to `*` quantifier) occurrences of:

  - `[,.]` - a comma or dot
  - `\d+` - one or more digits

Comment: Thank! is there any better resource to learn regular expression than MSDN page?

Comment: I can suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at. For testing .NET regex patterns, I can recommend [Ultrapico Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm).